# TkInter: how to get actual text modification?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to know where and what  was changed by user in tkinter's `Text` widget.

I've found how to get that text was *somehow* modified by using `<<Modified>>`event but I can't get actual changes:

```
from tkinter import *

def reset_modified():
    global resetting_modified
    resetting_modified = True
    text.tk.call(text._w, 'edit', 'modified', 0)
    resetting_modified = False

def on_change(ev=None):
    if resetting_modified: return
    print ("Text now:\n%s" % text.get("1.0", END))
    if False: # ???? 
        print ("Deleted [deleted substring] from row %d col %d")
    if False: # ????
        print ("Inserted [inserted substring] at row %d col %d")
    reset_modified()

resetting_modified = False
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(END, "Hello\nworld")
text.pack()
text.bind("<<Modified>>", on_change)
reset_modified()
root.mainloop()
```

For example, if I select 'ello' part from "hello\nworld" in `Text` widget then I press 'E', then I want to see

"Deleted [ello] from row 0 col 1" followed by "Inserted [E] at row 0 col 1"

is it possible to get such changes (or at least their coordinates) or I have basically to `diff` text on each keystroke if I want to detect changes run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catching the low level inserts and deletes performed by the underlying tcl/tk code is the only good way to do what you want. You can use something like `WidgetRedirector` or you can do your own solution if you want more control.

Writing your own proxy command to catch all internal commands is quite simple, and takes just a few lines of code. Here's an example of a custom Text widget that prints out every internal command as it happens:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import Tkinter as tk

class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """A text widget that report on internal widget commands"""
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self._orig = self._w + "_orig"
        self.tk.call("rename", self._w, self._orig)
        self.tk.createcommand(self._w, self.proxy)

    def proxy(self, command, *args):
        # this lets' tkinter handle the command as usual
        cmd = (self._orig, command) + args
        result = self.tk.call(cmd)

        # here we just echo the command and result
        print(command, args, "=>", result)

        # Note: returning the result of the original command
        # is critically important!
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    CustomText(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

After digging around, I've found that idlelib has WidgetRedirector which can redirect on inserted/deleted events:

```
from tkinter import *
from idlelib.WidgetRedirector import WidgetRedirector

def on_insert(*args):
    print ("INS:", text.index(args[0]))
    old_insert(*args)

def on_delete(*args):
    print ("DEL:", list(map(text.index, args)))
    old_delete(*args)
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(END, "Hello\nworld")
text.pack()
redir = WidgetRedirector(text)
old_insert=redir.register("insert", on_insert)
old_delete=redir.register("delete", on_delete)
root.mainloop()
```

Though it seems hacky. Is there a more natural way?